# Report generating tool for Microsoft Word (team-based)

Tags: document-management, version-control, microsoft-word, documentation-generator

**The Problem**

I work with a team of people where we frequently generate reports specific to clients, regions, and topics. Each time we begin a new report, we open up several older reports which cover the appropriate combination of these items, then copy/paste into the new document, make revisions as necessary, and publish. Errors inevitably come in, since this system requires the person beginning a new report to be familiar with all previous ones, or else take time talking to the rest of the team to figure this out.

**What we need**

We're looking for a tool that would allow individual report sections/paragraphs to be tagged and version controlled. This way, when we generate a new report, we could simply select the list of appropriate tags, and the most recent version of all applicable paragraphs/sections would be brought in. This could be directly in Word, or in an interface where it could easily be copy/pasted into Word, retaining basic formatting.

**Must-haves:**

- Free trial. The software can cost, but there should be a free trial so I can test it out in order to craft a demo for the team.
- Basic formatting. Things such as heading level, bold/italic, etc should be included.
- Links to sources/references. We cite our work and pull in data from external sources, so we need to track these as well.
- Attachments. Many sections will include a figure or graphic, so we need to include these.

**Nice-to-haves:**

- Version control. It's OK if we can only see the most recent version of a section, but seeing what changed from the last one would be helpful.
- Free-form commenting.
- Easy Sharepoint and/or Microsoft Word integration.
- "Field" compatibility, or some method of inserting names/dates as variables which can be updated from one central location.
- Web-based user interface. We have a server where we can install/run Windows or Linux apps if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered [Google Docs](https://www.google.com/docs/about/)? Granted, you (and all your colleagues/collaborators would) would need a Google account but for what it's worth, I find it quite powerful. And, if I understand your question correctly, it does what you need it to do:

- you can use it for free or you can opt for Google for Business (I cannot tell you what the difference between the two is as my team and I are using the free/personal version and it seems to suffice),
- it has almost the same formatting options as Microsoft Word,
- you can insert links, footnotes, quite similar to what you can do in Word,
- you can insert pictures, tables, diagrams, equations, charts, etc.
- you get version control, where you can see who changed what,
- you get commenting options,
- not sure what you mean by Word integration, but you can upload and download your Word documents

  > Open, and edit, and save Microsoft Word files with the [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/office-editing-for-docs-s/gbkeegbaiigmenfmjfclcdgdpimamgkj?hl=en) or app.
- you can tag selected paragraphs with one of the nifty add-ons like "Tag, Search and Summarize" (seems to work fine for me),
- not sure about "field" compatibility but I am pretty sure you will be able to find an add-on for this as well,
- and web-based user interface is a check, same as parallel connections and simultaneous working/editing.

It looks like something that might suit your needs. Maybe worth a look.

Comment: Moving to Google is not an option, unfortunately -- at least not on the timeframe in which I'm hoping to implement this!

Comment: Ah, ok. Sorry about that. If I find something else, I'll let you know :)